# ECS is not recognize the values of .env set in Container Definition

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, docker, amazon-ecs

## Goal

I'm trying to deploy my NodeJS ExpressJS API in a **Docker** container running in my EC2.

I'm not sure why my container does not recognize the value of my .env that I created via my container definition.

[image]

When I run `npm start` I got this error.

[image]

How would one go about debugging this further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any hints/suggestions / helps on this be will be much appreciated!

You might check for two things here one by one:

- That your env variables are actually properly passed to your running container (should be the case) by explicitly listing them from within container shell command like so:

  ```
  echo $ADMIN_PWD # and so on other variables to make sure they have values...
  ```

  My assumption is that you should see proper values here. If you don't then you should see if you wipe them out somehow during container init.
- If first step is ok, you should check if nodeJS is properly reading available ENV variables. There is a number of ways you could read them from your code (`process.env.VARNAME` or by reading them from `.env` file and by using other modules than `dotenv` to do so...). Check that on running container `.env` file is present and properly populated since it is often on `.gitignore`, and if you use any other module check that all required files are present on container.

Comment: Do I run this `echo $ADMIN_PWD` as soon as I ssh into my EC2 ?

Comment: or do I need to run it `docker exec -it acd7d5aa11d8 bash` ?

Comment: This should be tested from within your container, so after 'docker exec ...` command.